# Question about a sentence construction has/have

Tags: construction

I know that I should say"

He/She/It **has** something,

and

I/We/You/They **have** something.

I get confused with sentences such as:

> 1. he was having a good time
> 2. he is having a good time

In these two sentences, why do we use a variation of have instead of a variation of has?

Comment: Why are you asking about *why we put **have** instead of **has***, when your two examples don't include ***either*** of those two forms?

Comment: These are progressive aspect constructions, which require the present participle form of the verb, i.e. "having". There is no present participle "*hasing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't. You have correctly put *having*, which is not *have* or *has*.

It's the *is* and *was* which go with he/she/it, (as opposed to *are* and *were*).

Comment: is it correct to say they were having a hard time ? @colinfine

Comment: Yes, @HussamHamdeh, that's perfectly grammatical.